# How to enable offline support when using HTML5 history api

Tags: vue.js, offline, progressive-web-apps, html5-history, offline-mode

What are the best practices (and how to go about doing it) to support **offline** mode when using **html5 history api** for url rewrites?

For example, (hypothetically) I have a PWA SPA application at *https://abc.xyz* which has internationalization built in. So when I visit this link, the Vue router (which ideally could be any framework - vue, react, angular etc.) redirect me to *https://abc.xyz***/en**.

This works perfectly when I am online (ofcourse, the webserver is also handling this redirect so that app works even if you directly visit the said link).

However, its a different story when I am offline. The service worker caches all resources correctly so when I visit the URL *https://abc.xyz* everything loads up as expected. However, now if I manually type the URL to *https://abc.xyz***/en**, the app fails to load up.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Link to same question in github: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/188

Comment: Not sure that _can_ be achieved ... Your client-side routing can only take effect once your app is loaded - but if the user accesses `https://abc.xyz/en` _directly_, then who is going to load your app in the first place? The server could of course return the same code as if `/` was requested in this situation ... but “offline”, there is no one around who could perform this task in the first place.

Comment: Well, I could be wrong, but cant Service worker do this @CBroe? Afterall Service Workers are responsible for intercepting network requests, and ideally, this could and should be achievable... I am just not sure how to go about and do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible quite trivially with Service Workers. All you have to do is to configure the `navigateFallback` property of `sw-precache` properly. It has to point to the *cached asset* you want the service worker to fetch if it encounters a cache miss.

In the template you posted, you should be good to go if you configure your SWPrecache Webpack Plugin as follows:

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
    ...
    navigateFallback: '/index.html'
    ...
})
```

Again, it is absolutely mandatory that the thing you put inside `navigateFallback` is cached by the Service Worker already, otherwise this will fail silently.

You can verify if everything was configured correctly by checking two things in your webpack generated `service-worker.js`:

1. the precacheConfig Array contains `['/index.html', ...]`
2. in the fetch interceptor of the service worker (at the bottom of the file), the variable `navigateFallback` is set to the value you configured

If your final App is hosted in a subdirectory, for example when hosting it on Github pages, you also have to configure the `stripPrefix` and `replacePrefix` Options correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Georg Grab 

`new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
    ...
    navigateFallback: '/index.html'
    ...
}) `

did the trick for me. :)